# Avoid nesting from conjunction with function that returns 2 values in go?

Tags: go, nested, return-value

Here, I have a conjunction expression involving some functions that return 2 values:

```
if _, ok := f(); ok {
  if _, ok := g(); !ok {
    if h() {
      if _, ok := i(); ok {
        doStuff()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Could I somehow avoid the nesting? Instead of nesting, could I write this as an expression in one line (I can't quite break or return early in this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a helper function, you can.

Create a helper function which returns the second `bool` return value, e.g.:

```
func check(dummy interface{}, ok bool) bool {
    return ok
}
```

And using it:

```
if check(f()) && check(g()) && h() && check(i()) {
    doStuff()
}
```

Note that this is equivalent to the original code because the `&&` operator is evaluated from left to right and it is using [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation): if any of the operands evaluate to `false`, further operands (functions) will not be called.

This `check()` function works for all functions that return 2 values and the 2nd is of type `bool` (because any value can be assigned to a variable of type `interface{}`).

**This is covered in the [Spec: Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls):**

> As a special case, if the return values of a function or method `g` are equal in number and individually assignable to the parameters of another function or method `f`, then the call `f(g(parameters_of_g))` will invoke `f` after binding the return values of `g` to the parameters of `f` in order. The call of `f` must contain no parameters other than the call of `g`, and `g` must have at least one return value. If `f` has a final `...` parameter, it is assigned the return values of `g` that remain after assignment of regular parameters.

Note: since the first parameter in `check()` is not used, we can even use the blank identifier when naming it which will make it obvious that we don't use that parameter:

```
func check(_ interface{}, ok bool) bool {
    return ok
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid deep nesting or long conditionals running off the right side of the page with a function. For example,

```
package main

func f() (int, bool) { return 1, true }

func g() (int, bool) { return 1, true }

func h() bool { return true }

func i() (int, bool) { return 1, true }

func doStuff(f, g, i int) int { return f + g + i }

func andDoStuff() {
    ff, ok := f()
    if !ok {
        return
    }
    gg, ok := g()
    if !ok {
        return
    }
    if ok := h(); !ok {
        return
    }
    ii, ok := i()
    if !ok {
        return
    }
    doStuff(ff, gg, ii)

}

func main() {
    andDoStuff()
}
```

Comment: The asker specifically said he can't return early in his case.