# What's the difference between these two variants?

Tags: go, multiple-value

I tried to make my own code for learning how to return multiple values in main function:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Enter a integer:")
    var I int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &I)
    fmt.Println("Accepted:", I)

    O := half(I)
    fmt.Println("Returned:", O)
}

func half(N int) (int, bool) {
    var NA int
    NA = N / 2
    if NA%2 == 0 {
        fmt.Println("even")
        return NA, true
    } else {
        fmt.Println("odd")
        return NA, false
    }
}
```

And given error: `half.go|11| multiple-value half() in single-value context`.
However another variant are working:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func half(number int) (int, bool) {
    if x := int(number % 2); x == 0 {
        return x, true
    } else {
        return x, false
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(half(1))
    fmt.Println(half(2))
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How to overcome my error?

Answer (score 3):

If a function has 2 return values, you have to "expect" both of them or none at all. More on this: [Return map like 'ok' in Golang on normal functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487036/return-map-like-ok-in-golang-on-normal-functions/28487270#28487270)

Your `half()` function has 2 return values, so when using a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) to store the returned values in variables, you have to provide 2 variables:

```
O, even := half(I)
fmt.Println("Returned:", O, even)
```

In the second case, you're not storing the returned values, you are passing them to [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) which has the signature:

```
func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
```

`fmt.Println()` has a variadic parameter, so you can pass any number of arguments to it. What happens here is that all the multiple return values of `half()` are passed as the value of the variadic parameter of `Println()`. This is allowed and detailed in [Spec: Calls:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)

> As a special case, if the return values of a function or method `g` are equal in number and individually assignable to the parameters of another function or method `f`, then the call `f(g(parameters_of_g))` will invoke `f` after binding the return values of `g` to the parameters of `f` in order. The call of `f` must contain no parameters other than the call of `g`, and `g` must have at least one return value. If `f` has a final `...` parameter, it is assigned the return values of `g` that remain after assignment of regular parameters.

Note that when doing so, you are not allowed to pass / provide extra parameters, so for example the following is also a **compile-time error**:

```
fmt.Println("Returned:", half(10))
// Error: multiple-value half() in single-value context
```

Check out these similar questions:

[Go: multiple value in single-value context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227095/go-multiple-value-in-single-value-context/28233172#28233172)

[Avoid nesting from conjunction with function that returns 2 values in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548073/avoid-nesting-from-conjunction-with-function-that-returns-2-values-in-go/35548183#35548183)

Answer (score 1):

`fmt.Println` accepts any number of arguments, so is ok accepting the results of `half`.

In the first one, you need to provide places for both variables. Either:

`i,b := half(2)`

or

`i, _ := half(2)`

if you don't need the second return.